# Solving Second Order ODE in coordinate space

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I need to numerically compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the radial Schrodinger Equation in the case of a 3D and 2D Coulomb potential. The differential equation contains both the first and second derivative of R(r).

The problem is that scipy.integrate.ode or scipy.integrate.odeint require "initial values" for the function and its first derivative - every example I've seen online uses a differential equation in t, so that specifying the initial conditions of the system is trivial and arbitrary.

Since I am considering an ODE in space, not time, I should note that "initial conditions" should be more accurately called "boundary conditions". For my case, however, the function R(r) must only be finite at the origin, but there is no specific value it must take at r=0. Furthermore the derivative of the radial wavefunction, R', is physically meaningless and so constraining (or especially specifying) its value at the origin is nonsensical. The only definite boundary conditions present in the system is that the function must exponentially decay to zero for very large r.

In this case I am considering, instead of making the linspace count up from zero to some large number, make it count backwards from a large value to zero, for which I can set my "initial condition at r -> infinity" such that R and R' are zero.

Anyone else have this issue, and what workaround did you find for it?

Thank you!

Comment: The 3D case is the Hydrogen atom, for which there are analytical solutions. I'd start from there, with the same boundary conditions, to see if you can replicate the analytic solution numerically. With numerical simulations of this kind it is extremely important to start from a place with known solutions to generate an intuitition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential

Comment: I've already derived the eigenvalues and functions analytically, and now I need to check them numerically. So back to my question, since the only "hard" boundary conditions exist at infinity, would defining the linspace backwards work to overcome my problem?

Comment: As far as I understand is the radial probability density at r=0 identical to zero for all states 1s,2s,3s, 2p,3p,4p  etc.  So R(n,l)=0 for r=0

Comment: I had always thought this too, but no. For l = 0 in fact R(r=0) is never zero. This is because those wavefunctions always contain one term that is of degree r^0 but contains an exponential exp(-r/a0) (times constants). See [here](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~pascual/Vorlesung/WS06/slides%20FU/WS06%20EPIII-L6a.pdf). The forms given on that second slide are in agreement (up to constant factors coming from differing units) with the representation from Wikipedia, where for n,l=0, there are no factors of r anywhere except in the exponential, thus R is non zero at the origin.

Comment: Interestingly enough there is an error in Landau's Quantum Mechanics book - unexpected considering how highly regarded that book is (my personal opinion notwithstanding). In his formulation (Third Edition, section 36, page 121) the generalized Laguerre polynomial is said to have degree (n + l), which would mean the wavefunction has two terms in the ground state, of degree r^0 and r^1. Wikipedia's result, that L is of degree (n-l-1) seems to be correct.

Comment: Physically there has to be for say 1s a high density somewhere around the Bohr radius with a decline towards r=0 and r->infty. In an infinitely small sphere around zero the probability density has to be zero. But your point about the radial functions is correct, only the integral over a small sphere has to be zero, not the function itself. When people plot the radial probability they plot 4 pi r^2 * |Rnl|^2.

Comment: Right, so if you were to integrate in a small sphere around the proton, you would have a factor of r^2 in the integrand from the Jacobian, and the value of the function (r^2)*|Rnl|^2 is zero at the origin. The graphs from the slideshow linked above indicate that they are graphs of only R(r). I agree that it flies in the face of our intuition, but the math can't lie! The wavefunction simply is what it is, and what it is happens to be non zero at the origin for all n and l = 0. Edit: sorry, I didn't realize you were agreeing with me here.